# compiling project using curl on msvs2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, libcurl

I'm developing a dll that uses libcurl. I builded lib with `vc6curlsrc.dsw` project (I found it into `src` folder of curl distributive). After I add `libcurl.lib` to dependences of profect I get

```
main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__curl_easy_init referenced in function "private: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall ComappingApi::request(char * const)" (?request@ComappingApi@@AAE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@QAD@Z)
```

the same if I don't add `libcurl.lib` to dependences. Am I missing something!

Comment: The compiler assumed that curl was built as a DLL, evident from the __inp prefix.  High odds that libcurl.lib is actually a static library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the lib correctly linked to the project?

If so, check if you are not missing the CURL_STATICLIB definition in the project.

Comment: If wldap32.lib was missing, the linker would have reported different symbol!

Comment: @bronekk that's true, my bad! It seems that the libcurl.lib is not correct linked to the project. I will edit my answer